# Can OnBeforeUnload run code if they accept the dialog?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I want to control how easily people can leave my app. Now, I know I can't do it completely; that's what cron jobs are for. But I'd like to catch as many cases as possible.

I thought, I could use `onBeforeUnload` to display the dialog box, warning them about leaving and asking them to please click the Quit button instead.

But then I found out that it could be possible to run a synchronous AJAX (heh) call when `onBeforeUnload` is called; the benefit of it being synchronous is that the browser will wait for it to finish before continuing, as I understand it. That way, I could tell the server that I'm logging off as they close the window. And because it's in `onBeforeUnload` and not `onUnload`, all of the data is still extant and the call will be sent.

My question is, is it possible to combine these? I would like a popup warning them about leaving, and then IF they continue to want to leave, send the message that they are in fact leaving.

The way I understand it, I can't do this; I can do:

1. Send the message only
2. Put up the dialog only
3. Send the message *and* put up the dialog

... but I can't send the message *conditionally on if they accepted the dialog*, right? My understanding is that when they click "OK, I want to leave", it immediately fires `onUnload`, and by that point it's too late. And #3 above isn't useful because I don't want to send the message that they're logging off, and then have them cancel the dialog and stay on the page.

Can I have my cake and eat it too? Can I ask them if they want to leave and, if so, send the message?

Comment: Don't rely on `onbeforeunload` for these things, it's not fail-safe: this non-standard event isn't supported by Opera and therefore never fires. Moreover, killing a browser using a task manager or something (*nix `kill` command) also doesn't fire this event.

Comment: As I said right at the start of my post, I wasn't intending to *rely* on the browser for anything. That's what server-side cron jobs are for: catching ungraceful closings. I was hoping to make this close as graceful as possible and catch as many situations as possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I already stated in a comment, `onbeforeunload` doesn't function in Opera. However, I tried the following code in Firefox (3.6.3/Linux) and Chromium (5.0.375.70) and it worked more or less. However, when closing the Chromium window or tab, the confirmation box is shown, but within a second the window/tab is closed, even when clicking `Ok`. There seems to be a timeout for synchronous XMLHttpRequests during `onbeforeunload`.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (confirm("Send unsaved data?"))
        sendData();

};

function sendData() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "wait.php", false); // false = synchronous request
    request.send('data={"foo":"bar"}');
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
        alert("Succes!");

}
```

*Update* – Just for the sake of completeness, as I forgot to include `wait.php`, it just holds the connection for 10 seconds:

```
<?php sleep(10); ?>
```

Comment: This will likely only be used in FF and IE anyway, I'm not going out of my way to support Opera and Chrome (it's an in-house app). But that still sounds kind of sketchy. Based on what I'm seeing, I think I'd rather just throw my lot with `cron`. (Again, not that it wasn't going to exist *anyway*, I just wanted to see how graceful I could make closing the app. Not too much, it seems.)

Comment: @Andrew: Indeed. It's just that the web was not designed to do these kind of things.